# Creating a Custom Android Build for an Embedded Device without Permissions Request Screen

Tags: android-permissions, android-rom

I am using a Chinese S.O.M. for my embedded Android device. My counterparts, who should provide me with information for building the Android image, fail to understand my requirement: to prevent Android from requesting permission confirmation for my app (reading/writing to SD, accessing WIFI network). Does anyone know if it is possible to eliminate the permission request altogether or if there is another solution that can be implemented?